# Catching right mouse click on user control level

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <!-- multiple controls here -->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As the above example says, there are multiple MS / 3rd party controls hosted on UserControl. I need to catch mouse right click over the UserControl (or any of its child controls). It seems that [PreviewMouseRightButtonUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouserightbuttondown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event is not fired when clicked on some of the 3rd party controls inside the UserControl. As per documentation, PreviewMouseRightButtonUp is not a tunneling event, but a direct event, so it is possible that some 3d party controls do not notify the subscribers about this event.

I have also tried to add handler to this event, but still no result

```
AddHandler(UserControl.PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(GetHandledToo), true);
AddHandler(UserControl.PreviewMouseRightButtonUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(GetHandledToo), true);
AddHandler(UserControl.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(GetHandledToo), true);
AddHandler(UserControl.MouseRightButtonUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(GetHandledToo), true);
```

So, is there a way to always catch the right mouse button event on the user control level, no matter if it is being marked as handled or not?

**Edit**: I have found where the problem lies. The problem lies in the ContentControl which has not yet evaluated its content. Example:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="chart" Content="{Binding DiagramScreen}" />
```

ContentControl recolves its structure through DataTemplate. If DiagramScreen is NULL, the ContentControl's content is not yet created. This means that the space that this ContentControl occupies in UserControl is not responding to Mouse events. How Can I make ContentControl respond to mouse events, even if its content is NULL?

Comment: I can't understand your words since I don't have good English skill. (1) Is it important that the multiple controls are 3rd party controls? (2) If you want catch mouse event of child control on parent control before child control, you should use just mouse event not preview mouse event. (3) If you set event handle property to true in chained method to mouse event of parent control, you can prevent that the child control catch mouse event.

Comment: @WonHyoungLee (2) mouse event (ex MouseRightButtonUp) is first raised on child control (behaves like a bubble event), and not the parent control (3) this is true for tunneling events, and MouseRightButtonUp event is not a tunneling event. If you try what you are suggesting, you will see that it is not working

Comment: It's my mistake. you should use preview mouse event,not mouse event. I just test UserControl / Grid / Border / Rectangle, It's working. So, what is you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

I think if it is handled you can't get it further for bubbling event. A workaround is to pass your host object to your user control. After that, you can call whatever method you want from your host object. It's ugly but I think it will work

Comment: This is expected for bubbling event, but is there some tunneling event? Even so, if a bubbling event is handled, should it still not be picked if we have added handler through AddHandler method, passing true to handledEventsToo parameter?

Comment: CMIIW, but for each bubbling event there will be a tunneling as its pair. It has naming standard like this Preview<eventName> e.g. PreviewMouseRightButtonDown. Please check it out
Edit :

As documentation said https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx Rightmousdown is direct. I think you should implement MouseDown and PreviewMouseDown because they are bubble and tunnel event

Comment: I have found the problem, and edited the question for more information.